# Redirecting standard I/O: freopen + stdin/stdout vs open + dup2

Tags: c++, linux, unix, io-redirection

I want to redirect stdin/stdout to some file. The program is being written for Unix OS but I think using standart C/C++ library instead of OS functions is good. I know how I can do that using OS functions `dup2()` and `open()` but I read some ways to do that using `reopen()` on `stdin` or `stdout`. Will reopening standart variables do what I want? Will it replace files opened at 0 and 1 file descriptors? Which way is better?

Comment: Why not just redirect via the command line ?

Comment: @Paul R Because what I am doing is writing my own shell.

Comment: @H2CO3 C++ but, if it matters, I'm using printf and other C-functions a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are writing your own shell, I would use the lower level functions of dup2() and open().

freopen() on stdin will close the original stdin, and open the file you asked for, at the stdin position - so you have now lost stdin. Not that it makes much difference if you use open() and dup2() to replace file handle 0 or 1, of course - you still lose the original stdin, so only do this after you have forked.

Comment: But I can save original stdin or 0/1 fd and then restore them, can't I?